# How can I split a set of bytes into separate parts

Tags: linux, shell, split, byte

```
$ du -b 1GB.bin
1048576000      1GB.bin

$ split --verbose -b 120M 1GB.bin && du -b *xa*
125829120       xaa
125829120       xab
125829120       xac
125829120       xad
125829120       xae
125829120       xaf
125829120       xag
125829120       xah
41943040        xai
```

How can I split or divide the `1048576000 bytes` above, or even bigger: `2GiB = 2147483648 bytes` or `3GiB = 3221225472 bytes` and so on, but without having to use the split utility, so that the result is exactly as above (per part is `120 MiB = 125829120 bytes`, except for the last part, `40 MiB = 41943040 bytes`) ?.

Comment: What's the reason you can't use the split utility? Are there other constraints here?

Comment: The file hosting where I put the files allows for multipart uploads without having to split files.

Comment: The `du` output posted for the `split` files match your requirement perfectly. Not clear how this affects *"allows for multipart uploads without having to split files"*. Either the files are split into sections or they are not split, right? Edit your question (NOT IN COMMENTS) to show what your desired set of files would look like to work with your *"file hosting where I put the files"*. Good luck.
*

Answer (score 1):

The simple and POSIX-standard way to split files is using `split`.

It is unclear why you don't want to use this.

Another standard way to split files is using `dd` with its `skip=` and `count=` parameters, but this is much more tedious.
The hardest part is to generate the filenames.
This can be done using bash **brace expansion**, or a nested `for` loop in any POSIX shell:

```bash
mysplit_bash()( 
   bash -c '
      if=$1
      bs=${2:-12589120}
      n=0
      for of in x{a..z}{a..z}; do
         dd if="$if" of=$of bs=$bs count=1 skip=$((n++)) 2>&-
         [ -s $of ] || break
      done
      rm $of
   ' -- "$@"
)

mysplit_sh()(
   if=$1
   bs=${2:-12589120}
   n=0
   set -- a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
   for i; do
      for j; do
         of=x$i$j
         dd if="$if" of=$of bs=$bs count=1 skip=$n 2>&-
         [ -s $of ] || break 2
         n=$(expr $n + 1)
      done
   done
   rm $of
)
```

Add your own error-checking.

Invoke with filename to split as first argument and optionally chunksize (in form understood by `dd`) as second argument.

These functions will produce incorrect output if the input file would need to be split into more than 675 parts.